# Why is element height retrieved using javascript is larger than actual rendered height in Flutter webview on Android?

Tags: android, flutter, webview

I'd like to display a webview widget among others in ListView in Flutter using webview_flutter. The webview widget must be the size of the rendered content (which is basically only 1 banner in the entire page) therefore I try to retrieve the height of the rendered element and set it as the height of the widget:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class Banner extends StatefulWidget {
  const Banner({super.key});

  @override
  State<Banner> createState() => _BannerState();
}

class _BannerState extends State<Banner> {
  late final WebViewController _controller;

  double height = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    final WebViewController controller = WebViewController();

    controller
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onPageFinished: (String url) async {
            Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () async {
              var bannerHeight = await controller.runJavaScriptReturningResult(
                "document.querySelector('#banner').offsetHeight",
              ) as num;

              setState(() {
                height = bannerHeight.toDouble();
              });
            });
          },
        ),
      )
      ..loadRequest(
        Uri.parse(
          "https://...",
        ),
      );

    _controller = controller;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: height,
      child: WebViewWidget(
        controller: _controller,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This works fine on iOS but on Android the height returned by the JS code is bigger than what is actually being rendered, therefore leaving a white space between the end of the html content and the end of the widget.

I tried to increase the timeout before requesting the element height, but that does not change anything. Based on experimenting with the served html/css it seems that breaking (regular) spaces messes up the numbers. If I swap all breaking spaces in the html textnodes with non-breaking spaces, the returned height is in line with what is being rendered. As a matter of fact I don't even have to swap all spaces to non-breaking ones, just a couple.